# LINQ for sum data in DataView group by column results error?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I am getting the following error:

> Specified cast is not valid

The following row is highlighting this after error `row.Field<DateTime>("DATE")`.

This is my code:

```
var query = from row in _Hdt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<DateTime>("DATE") into grp
            orderby grp.Key
            select new
            {
               Date = grp.Key,
               Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("KW"))
            };

            foreach (var grp in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", grp.Date, grp.Sum);
            }
```

Comment: Mb your `row.Field<DateTime>("DATE")` isn't of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Any info about what _Hdt is or what _Hdt Contains?

Comment: may be you should check "DATE" for DbNull.Value before group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database column type is really compatible to DateTime, and if the table contains Null values in that column.

Null cannot be converted to DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
row.Field<DateTime?>("DATE")
```

or

```
row.Field["DATE"] as DateTime?
```